# jQuery3 animate() bugs when used on rotated elements (swaps height and width)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have some rotated images, using simple CSS Transform.

Those are also zoomable, and I'm trying to use jQuery animate to ease the zooming.

But whenever animate is used on a rotated image, the starting frame of the animation has the height and width of the image swapped.

I made a simple fiddle here so you can see for yourself : https://jsfiddle.net/4ancpyuo/7/

Here is a stackoverflow version, showing the problem is **not** present on jQuery2 :

```js
var params = {
  width: 142,
  height: 48
};
$("#animatebutton").click(function() {
  $("#logo").animate(params, 1000);
});
```

```css
#logo {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 142px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/GoogleLogoSept12015.png">
<button id="animatebutton">Animate</button>
```

The Animate button transform the Google logo to it's current height and width over 1 second... which means clicking it shouldn't do anything.
But when you click it on JSFiddle, you should instead see both attributes being swapped and recovering over 1 second.

Is this a bug in the animate function? Any workaround?

Thanks

Edit: I simply switched to jQuery2 for now, didn't pose any problem in my other functions.